# best way to format and view wording in ie7

Tags: html

i have a T&C doc that is quite lengthy...as it is now it views perfect in FF and chrome:

```
<div id='div_longgray_gradient2'>
<table class='table_format_content_rbc' border='0' >
<tr>
<td colspan='3' align='ceter'> 
  <span class='spn_big_lightblue_rbc'>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</span>
</td>   
</tr>
<tr>        
<td colspan='3' align='left'> 
        &nbsp;<br/>
</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='left'> 
By entering this site you confirm that you are at least 16 years of age.
    <br/>
<pre style='font-family:Arial, sans-serif; width:auto; white-space:pre-wrap;'>
For purposes of this agreement you are identified as ‘The Member’.

By entering this site and confirming that you have read and understood the terms and 
and so it goes on and and on and on.

And many more sentences.
</pre>
</td>
```

how can i do the same for IE7 without doing a <p> and <br/> for every sentence?? as it shows now it just has the whole thing as one continuous line!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you have provided is not very well formed, it would be better to lose the `<pre>` tag and place `<br />` and `<p>` tags in the required location. The whole idea of HTML is that it is Markup Language and should be used to describe how the document is rendered. If you must go down the `<pre>` tag route then you are probably best looking at what dtd you are using at the top of the document and what rendering mode IE is rendering the document in(if you have IE8+ press F12).

Thanks

Nicholas

Comment: i have ie7 running on ubuntu 10.4...ie8 and ie9 is not yet supported for playonlinux and have problems installing ie8 using winetricks... this code was inherited from some-one who did not make provision for viewing in any IE :( :(

Comment: The best way forward is to recode it and put in the appropriate p and br tags, its a 5 min job to sort out. :-)